# What is the difference between these two Axios upload methods?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, axios

I have 2 different [axios](/questions/tagged/axios) POST calls. The first one makes use of the `.post` method and this successfully uploads the image to the database.

```
  return axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload", data, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log("The response", response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("Error", error);
        });
```

However the method below does not seem to work properly and throws an error in the database / backend. But it does use the exact same configuration... :

**Axios call that makes use of the Network utility function:**

```
return httpPost(
        process.env.NODE_ENV
          ? `https://tabbs-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/upload`
          : `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload`,
        {
          data
        },
        null
      )
        .then(response => {
          console.log("uploaded", response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("Error", error);
        });
```

**Network Utility function:**

```
export function httpPost(url, data, token) {
  return axios({
    method: "post",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer" + " " + token,
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are calling `httpPost` with an object that has `data` as its only key, but your original `axios` call is made with just `data` as a plain-old object. Is this difference intentional? We don't know the context of the `httpPost` call, or the error content, so it's going to be difficult for us to diagnose the error...

Comment: @AndyTaton I am not sure. I thought this was part of the config of Axios. How would you alter this?

Comment: replace your call: `return httpPost(url, {data}, config)` with: `return httpPost(url, data, config)`

Comment: That is, unless you intentionally want your `httpPost` function to have a different argument pattern from `axios.post`. This is your design decision, but it kind of seems like you are trying to make `httpPost` have the same interface as `axios.post`. Is that right?

Comment: @AndyTaton I kinda tried to make some sort of generic post call that takes an url, optional data, and optional token. That was my guess when making this Utility function.

Comment: Okay, so: 1) What happened when you took my first suggestion and removed the curly braces from `{ data }` in your Network utility function? 2) How is `httpPost` called? Can you please provide a code example of how the `data` is prepared and used in the function call? 3) What is the error you are getting? Can you provide the content of the error please?